# Good pagination performance for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, my table has this data:

```
id(auto increment)     :place     :views
1                      :test1     :20
2                      :test2     :50
3                      :test3     :30
```

I'm thinking about pagination system.

When I sort views, I use this sql.

```
select * from table order by views desc;
```

Here is result:

```
id    :place    :views
2     :test2    :50
3     :test3    :30
1     :test1    :20
```

I'd like to use this data for pagination.

```
Page 1:
select * from table order by views desc limit 0, 2;
Page 2:
select * from table order by views desc limit 2, 2;
```

However, if this table has many data, the DB performance is lazy.

I found good slide for this problem.
http://www.slideshare.net/Eweaver/efficient-pagination-using-mysql

But, my data doesn't have sortable id.

I'm searching any good idea.

Comment: what type of data is the views column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement efficent "next page" functionality, if `id` is UNIQUE in mytable:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_IX1 ON mytable (views, id);
```

For the first page:

```
SELECT id, place, views 
  FROM mytable
 ORDER BY views DESC, id DESC
 LIMIT 2
```

Retrieve the rows. If you got the full two rows, there might be more rows, so keep the `views` and `id` values from that "last" row, for use in "next page" query.

For the next page, use the values of `views` and `id` that were saved  from the "last row" from previous page:

```
SELECT id, place, views
  FROM mytable
 WHERE views <= :pp_views AND ( id < :pp_id OR views < :pp_views )
 ORDER BY views DESC, id DESC
 LIMIT 2
```

If you get the full two rows, then you can get a "next page", just again use `views` and `id` values from "last row" of previous page, query is exactly the same:

```
SELECT id, place, views
  FROM mytable
 WHERE views <= :pp_views AND ( id < :pp_id OR views < :pp_views )
 ORDER BY views DESC, id DESC
 LIMIT 2
```

It's not clear why this approach doesn't work for you. Do you not have a unique column on the table you can use? (Your question suggests you have a unique (auto_increment) `id` column.)

Comment: Perfect!
I learned a lot from here.

    WHERE views <= :pp_views AND ( id < :pp_id OR views < :pp_views )
    ORDER BY views DESC, id DESC

Thanks a lot!

Comment: One other small enhancement for you to consider: determining whether there's at least one more row beyond the last one to be displayed. Exactly the same SQL, but `LIMIT 3` (one more than the page size). Use the first two rows returned for diaplay, save the `views` and `id` values from the 2nd row (the last row to be display on the page). If a 3rd row isn't returned, you know there's no more rows, so don't allow user opportunity to post a "next page" request. (You could give user indication there are no more pages to be displayed.)

Answer (score 0):

in your case i would index views and next be a link to last shown id in your example next would be `&index=3`

then the query would be getting the views id 3 has and then searching less than that with the limit.